# Extract text from image with pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I tried extract numbers from original image https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwRSL.jpg , but with no luck.

Output from pytesseract is: "[a ]:[4] G2):Go] [7 ):Ce J"

Thank you for advice,

My code:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'folder /tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread("folder /test_image.png")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The README says that OpenCV images are in BGR format and pytesseract assumes RGB format, so you need to [convert it](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)

```py
import cv2

img_cv = cv2.imread(r'/<path_to_image>/digits.png')

# By default OpenCV stores images in BGR format and since pytesseract assumes RGB format,
# we need to convert from BGR to RGB format/mode:
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb))
# OR
img_rgb = Image.frombytes('RGB', img_cv.shape[:2], img_cv, 'raw', 'BGR', 0, 0)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it does not help me, I got same output in pytesseract.